# Angular 2 How to call a component method from index.html(script)?

Tags: angular

I am able to catch event fired from silver-light in index.html(angular 2 code base) but i am stuck how to pass event to component method.

Comment: Show some piece of code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: ** index.html [code]<script.>function OpenMadRulePopup(){
        // here call component method
    }</script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am not sure if is what you looking for, but let assum on your html something happen like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Helper to create custom event with IE11 compatibility.
    function RsCustomEvent ( event, params ) {
        params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
        var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
        evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
        return evt;
    }
    // Something happen, you want to fire your event.
    window.dispatchEvent(RsCustomEvent('myCustomEvent'));
</script>
```

Then on you angular application, you can capture it like this :

```
// on your Angular code (component, service, directive ...)
Observable.fromEvent(window,'myCustomEvent').subscribe(() => {
    // Do what ever you want
}));
```

Important information : Be careful to fire your event **after** you app are initialize and Subscribe is done.